Split array of objects from MQTT into dynamoDB with IoTCore rule
I'm trying to find away that allows me to split an array of objects into DynamoDB table entries.
The message arrives via AWS IoTCore shadow file, and I'm trying to create a rule that takes the below message and splits the array into database entries using the DynamoDBv2 rule action.
{
    "state": {
        "reported": {
            "array": [
                {
                    "param": 123,
                    "timestamp": 12341234
                },
                {
                    "param": 124,
                    "timestamp": 12341235
                }
            ],
            "param1": 1,
            "param2": 2
        },
        "desired":
        {}
    }
}

The SQL statement I have is below. Cloudwatch reports that there is no timestamp attribute, indicating that its not splitting. The array is of arbitrary length, so I can't hard code it
SELECT state.reported.array.* , topic(3) as deviceID FROM '$aws/things/+/shadow/name/myShadow/update/accepted'

Ive looked at the nested object examples, although it doesn't really cover my use case.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-nested-queries.html
